# Adjust Datetime column on x-axis of matplotlib in time series dataset

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, machine-learning, time-series

I'm working with time-series dataset, this dataset has a `timestemp` column which I set as the index column of the dataset, it has the vale of date and time also in the form as:
`15/5/17 7:51` so when I display a plot the date and time on x-axis make this this graph very difficult to understand.

Here's what I have tried to adjust the date and time on x-axis:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17, 4))
ax.plot(data,
        '-o',
        color='purple')
ax.set(xlabel="Date",
       title="Blood gclucose and heart rate distribution")

# Format the x axis
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(interval=0))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%m/%d"))

plt.show()
```

But it's not displaying any date on the x-axis, what can be wrong? and what I can do to make this datetime on x-axis more readable?

Comment: matplotlib often has issues with dates. If you use pandas for your data you can set the date column as index and plot index on x-axis. This works well all the time.

Comment: @pavel  can you put an example code, please!

Comment: With pandas you can do ```df.set_index('date')``` Then when you go to plot: ```ax.plot(df.index, df.data, '-o', color-'purple')```